# split lines into segments without creating new layer in QGIS

Tags: line, splitting, image-segmentation

How to split line objects into segments/multiple objects based on either polygons or lines without creating a new layer? The problem is clarified in the picture below. I need the green line to be segmented according to the pink lines or green polygons. [image]

Comment: Why is it so important to not to create a new layer? Basically every semi-automated process in Qgis creates a new (temporary) layer, in order to prevent users from erasing data. You can use the Advanced digitizing tools and separate everything manually, but that can be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

To split the line without creating another layer you can use the tool "Split Features" . This tool is available in the "Advanced Digitizing Toolbar".

This type of tool is important when you can not, or you do not want to generate another layer, such as when the layer you are working with is stored in a database.

Split features button:

[image: Split features button]

Advanced Digitizing Toolbar:

[image: Advanced Digitizing Toolbar]